# Можно ли собрать csproj с помощью gcc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gcc, build, csproj

Возникла проблема с установкой Visual Studio на 32 битную систему. Если можно с помощью gcc проект собрать, то подскажите команду пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы видите [в документации](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html) C#? Я нет. C# легко собирается штатными инструментами (включая консоль), особенно .NET.

Comment: Спасибо зв подсказку. Я нашёл решение с помощью MsBuild

Comment: MsBuild - это в основном .NET Framework, который устарел в мире C#. Проекты .NET спокойно собираются простым `dotnet build`.

Comment: Ставьте x64 систему, пора бы уже.